# How to enable didSelectRow on selecting an element included inside the cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

Well I have gone through web to search an easy implementation of this question but all I heard is coincide with what I thought at beginning which is not easy enough.

I was wondering if anybody could provide a better and easier implementation to solve this issue.

Well looking at the picture below, (Please neglect the crudeness of the picture)

[image]

I have a table view with multiple cells.
And based on the data, there will be different element(s) inside each cell.

If I touch inside the scrollview in cell 2 as shown in the picture. The delegate method for the tableView "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" will **NOT** be called, which is a problem for me.

So my first thinking is either to trigger the [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath] within the Scrollviews delegate method or I attach another tapGesture to these subviews and trigger it from there. But it already doesn't sound like a intuitive implementation and hard to maintain.

Anybody got any idea how could this be solved in an easier way?

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying your problem is that didSelectRowAtIndexPath in cell 2 is not called when touched but you want it to be called?

Comment: Do you need the user to interact with ScrollView inside cell 2?

Comment: @HossamGhareeb, yes, I need user to be able to interact with the scroll view, at the same time make the didSelectRow getting called.

Comment: @sangony, what I want to do is that when the user is interacting with the scroll view I hope the didSelectRow called as well, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a wide variety of objectives you might be trying to accomplish here, so I won't speculate on the ultimate goal which you haven't told us, but in general:

If you would like two different UIElements to execute the same chunk of code, then you encapsulate that code in a stand-alone method, and call that method from both places.

In your UIScrollView as a subview of a UITableViewCell example, you would call it from within   `-(void)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath`   and you would also call it from the gesture recognizer that you attached to your scrollView.

I will speculate that the part you're having trouble with is knowing which scrollView was touched, or which row the scrollView was in. One possible approach would be to send the UIScrollView or the UITableViewCell as a parameter for the standalone method you created.  `-(void)doSomethingSpecialWith:(UITableViewCell*)cell`  or `-(void)doSomethingSpecialWith:(UIScrollView)view`

Post some more code, or feel free to explain your agenda further, but I have a strong feeling that the best way for you will be to subclass UITableViewCell, add the UIScrollView as a property of the custom cell, and wire up the gesture recognizer to call a method of your subclassed UITableViewCell.

Comment: you are definite right. My ultimate goal is when the "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" is called, I will change the background colour of the cell so that it looks as highlighted. I think your suggestion could be a good solution to my problem, but I want to wait a little while for some other options. thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think the better way to solve this problem is :
creat custom method , - (void)tableviewSeletedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

you can call this method in TableView`s delegate -(void)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath , and call this method in your scroll`s method.

Answer (score 0):

Make the tag of scrollView is equal to the current cell row:

```
scrollView.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Make your ViewController to be the delegate of UIScrollView and in didScroll get the index and call didSelect:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
   NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:scrollView.tag inSection:0];

   [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:index];
}
```